# Transactions from multiple addresses to a single address in Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, raw-transaction, payments

We are currently in the process of developing a payment plugin for merchants to accept crypto payments. We are currently generating a unique order for every order which is placed in the merchant store. We easily implemented BTC, BCH and LTC since they support multiple UTXO transactions.

I went through most of the posts in the forum and noticed that this is not possible in ethereum using JSON RPCs just outside the box. Can someone please guide me if there is an alternate way to implement transactions from multiple addresses to a single address using Ethereum or if there is a better way to deal with merchant based transactions?

Thanks!

Comment: In Ethereum, every transaction has a single `from` address, so the method you used for Bitcoin etc. won't work here. There are two popular options: 1) Use a single address, but indicate via call data or the amount itself what order each payment corresponds to, or 2) Use multiple addresses, but have each be a smart contract that automatically forwards funds it receives.

Comment: The second option totally makes sense! But when i forward eth from a contract to another address, won't it cost more gas and be recorded as a separate transaction in the blockchain?

Comment: If you just forward immediately when ether is received (e.g. in the contract's fallback function), no separate transaction is required. But yes, it will cost more gas (~9,000, so it will add about 45% to the transaction fee.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have looked at a few forwarder contracts in solidity. Hopefully, they do the trick

Comment: You were right! It worked. But i am just curious if this is the only way to implement an ethereum based payment system since this requires me to implement one contract per order/transaction to track separate buyer payments and requires me to spend my own money on deploying each of these contracts!

Comment: My very first reply already mentioned another popular alternative.

Comment: The problem with the alternative is that making the user enter the data in an ethereum transaction might not be a very user friendly way to design the application since an average user might not know its functionality causing the transaction to fail.

Comment: Typically in Ethereum, you build a DApp: in-browser code that prepares the transactions for the user. They just have to authorize the transaction. They don't know/care that there's an order number encoded in there somewhere.

Comment: If you expect people to instead transfer the ether directly from something like Coinbase, just put the order number in the lower order bits of the amount. E.g. instead of charging 0.1 ether == 100000000000000000 wei, charge them 100000000000123456 wei, where 123456 is the order number. (The extra is about a billionth of a penny.)

Comment: Thanks! I am going to further explore smart contracts and figure out how to avoid someone spamming the smart contracts creation to avoid the faucet getting drained.